# Can I supply a predefined component/template with an Angular structural directive?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a series of input fields throughout my application that I want to provide a custom validation directive to. I would like this directive to include an icon, and some custom validation code. How can I get this icon element to display when I use my directive with inputs throughout my app?

Basic problem: I want to provide a custom HTML element as a part of my directive.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would recommend creating another directive that you attach to a `<ng-template>`. That directive then calls a shared service and passes a `TemplateRef` that will be used as the default. The structural directive gets the default from the share service (use an observable). You have to use this default directive in the AppComponent to set a default template for the app.

Comment: Interesting approach! Thanks for the thoughts, seems like that could be my solution.